# How to cancel a NSIS setup without showing a confirmation message box?

Tags: installation, nsis, messagebox, modern-ui

Having a NSIS setup with [Modern UI 2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html), the user gets a message box to confirm when he clicks on the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button in the installation wizard.

I want the user to be able to exit the installation wizard *without* confirming an additional "Are you sure?" dialog message box.

In the MUI sources I found this fragment:

```
!macro MUI_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING

  Function .onUserAbort

    !ifdef MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING
      Call ${MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING}
    !endif

    !ifdef MUI_ABORTWARNING
      !insertmacro MUI_ABORTWARNING
    !endif

    !ifdef MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT
      Call "${MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT}"
    !endif
  FunctionEnd

!macroend
```

I am both able to define the `MUI_PAGE_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING` function and the `MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT` function.

Since the actual message box is defined in the middle call to the `MUI_ABORTWARNING` macro, I see no way to stop the macro from being called.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to hinder MUI from showing the user a confirmation message box when he clicks the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button during the setup process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is controlled by `!define MUI_ABORTWARNING` (Before you include mui.nsh):

```
Name "Test"
Outfile "Test.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user

#Comment/uncomment this to toggle the messagebox: !define MUI_ABORTWARNING

!include MUI2.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anders, I [tried this](http://pastebin.com/HATfCZH8) and it does not seem to work. I click `Cancel` on the welcome page and still get a question whether I want to quit. Since I know the high quality of your answers, I wonder where I made the error in [my script](http://pastebin.com/HATfCZH8). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand; line 12 is the `!define MUI_ABORTWARNING` that you suggested to insert. I'm confused...

Comment: This is crazy; the line was not present before, then I added it, now I commented it out and now the message box really disappeared. So it is working right now, although I have no clue why.

Answer (score 1):

(untested) you can try to undefine the corresponding funcs ?

```
!undef MUI_ABORTWARNING
//or
!undef MUI_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING
```

Comment: Thanks, @Seki - I already tried this (and hust tried it again). It keeps giving the error message "`!undef: "MUI_ABORTWARNING" not defined!`"

Comment: MUI_FUNCTION_ABORTWARNING is a macro and cannot be !undef'ed